# How send sms in php?

Tags: php, sms, semaphore

How do I fix this issue? I cannot send sms on my work.

```
$ch = curl_init(); //curl()
$parameters = array(
  'apikey' => '', //Your API KEY
  'number' => '',//number
  'message' => 'I just sent my first message with Semaphore', //message
  'sendername' => 'SEMAPHORE');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://semaphore.co/api/v4/messages');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

//Send the parameters set above with the request
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $parameters ) );
```

How do I fix this issue? I have my apikey in semaphore.

Comment: According to the doc, the url should be: `https://api.semaphore.co/api/v4/messages`, you are missing the sub-domain part

Comment: this code given in semaphore.

Comment: https://api.semaphore.co/api/v4/messages, is not working also

Comment: you got message id from return response ?

Comment: try to print response and check 

$output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close ($ch);

//Show the server response

echo $output;

Comment: no response from server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 $ch = curl_init(); 
 $parameters = array(
          'apikey' => '', 
          'number' => '9000000000',
          'message' => 'I just sent my first message with Semaphore', 
          'sendername' => 'SEMAPHORE'
          );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://semaphore.co/api/v4/messages' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

//Send the parameters set above with the request
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $parameters ) );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    print_r($error_msg);
}
curl_close($ch);
exit;
```

Comment: what if more than 1 numbers.

Comment: enter mobile numbers with coma

Comment: @Dharman he found that out, that on test server he can do this but on production he'll have to keep it on. he was probably facing the issue because of ssl on test server.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i tried this code and print output

```
    <?php
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

$ch = curl_init();
$parameters = array(
    'apikey' => '', //Your API KEY
    'number' => '0987654321',//for testing no 
    'message' => 'I just sent my first message with Semaphore',
    'sendername' => 'SEMAPHORE'
);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://semaphore.co/api/v4/messages' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

//Send the parameters set above with the request
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $parameters ) );

// Receive response from server
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close ($ch);

//Show the server response

echo $output;
```

i got return output

`"message_id":73840803,`

`"status":"Pending",`

Using live key and test and try to hit same code check status is pending to received

Comment: login your SMS gateway panel and check you received messages

Comment: what if more than 1 number

Comment: try to use bulk sms and every no after ,

like 

no1,no2,no3